# consuming uri with jwt Token using REST in springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jwt

I have a "jwt token" given by some third party source and "URI", while consuming this I'm using "RestTemplate". My code looks like below:

```
@GetMapping("/xyz")
public String account(){
   HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();       

   headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);

   headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    HttpEntity<String> entity=new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    String responseEntity = this.restTemplate.getForObject(My_SERVICE_URI, String.class, entity);

    return responseEntity;
}
```

I have hardcoded URl and JWT token in my java class as

```
public static final String My_SERVICE_URI ="https://some uri";
private String token ="some token";
```

while hitting the url `localhost:8080/xyz`
I'm getting error as:

> 401:UnAuthorized and 500 internal server error.

Please let me know if I'm consuming the rest call in a wrong way.
Note: I had tried with `restTemplate.exchange(...);` also.

Comment: are you sure about this line `headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);`. You should check with the third party source, how the token needs to be sent.

Comment: yes, token given by third party is bearer